# How did Japan’s Hayabusa 2 mission "make extensive use of deployable cameras to get scientific imagery"? Did it ever produce a "PR selfie"?

Tags: mission-design, camera, jaxa, hayabusa2

Scott Manley's recent video [China's Mars Rover Zhurong Has Completed Its Primary Mission, Reaches New Milestone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSSs6FfBlgY) includes the following:

> And if you thought that dropping a camera on the surface of Mars to take a photo of your rover was cool, well they dropped a camera off in deep space so it could take a photograph of the spacecraft *in flight.* Japan’s Hayabusa 2 mission made extensive use of deployable cameras to get scientific imagery, but these amazing images are entirely there for their PR value.

**Question:** How did Japan’s Hayabusa 2 mission "make extensive use of deployable cameras to get scientific imagery"? Did it ever produce a "PR selfie"?

[image: screenshot from Scott Manley's video China's Mars Rover Zhurong Has Completed Its Primary Mission, Reaches New Milestone https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSSs6FfBlgY]

Answer (score 1):

If we discount photos of Hayabusa 2 such as this taken by its own cameras:

[image: Image taken 4 seconds before touchdown with CAM-H (image credit: JAXA).]
*Image taken 4 seconds before touchdown with CAM-H
(image credit: JAXA).*

then the only image I could find of the Hayabusa 2 from one of its rover/hoppers is this:

[image: Image captured by Rover-1A on September 21 at around 13:08 JST. This is a color image taken immediately after separation from the spacecraft. Hayabusa2 is at the top and the surface of Ryugu is bottom. (image credit: JAXA)]

*Image captured by Rover-1A (Minerva-II1) on September 21 at around 13:08 JST.
This is a color image taken immediately after separation from the spacecraft.
Hayabusa2 is at the top and the surface of Ryugu is bottom (image credit: JAXA)*

There are a couple of pictures of the landers taken by the main spacecraft taken shortly after they were deployed.

[image: The Minerva-II2 rover soon after separating from the Hayabusa 2 spacecraft (image credit: JAXA)]
*The Minerva-II2 rover soon after separating from the Hayabusa 2 spacecraft
(image credit: JAXA)*

[image: Image of Mascot from Hayabusa 2 (image credit: JAXA)]

*Image of Mascot from Hayabusa 2 (image credit: JAXA)*

The JAXA website for Hayabusa2 is [here](https://www.hayabusa2.jaxa.jp/en/).  There is [at least one study](https://www.science.org/doi/abs/10.1126/science.aaw8627) of the composition of Ryugu based on MASCOT images.