# Does JWST have any cameras to monitor its deployment?

Tags: james-webb-telescope

This question was asked here: [Does the JWST have a camera to monitor its deployment progress?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14346/does-the-jwst-have-a-camera-to-monitor-its-deployment-progress) several years ago; I am re-asking in case the situation changed between the time it was answered and its eventual launch a few days ago. All things considered, it would seem that visual inspection could be worth the cost to aid in troubleshooting any difficulties or forensically investigating a malfunction. Or is such a measure unnecessary due to redundancies, position/force sensors and a deep understanding of all possible failure modes?

Comment: The site doesn't permit duplicate questions for any reason. If those answers are old, downvote the outdated answer and upvote or supply a newer answer. And, if you want to help the site bounty that question for more attention and a newer answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the JWST have a camera to monitor its deployment progress?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14346/does-the-jwst-have-a-camera-to-monitor-its-deployment-progress)

Comment: As the one that posted the original answer, that answer is still valid.

Comment: @AnthonyX I managed to get away with it once, just barely, but it was extraordinary circumstances (I think). I think the best way to proceed in general, (either with a reopen or a new question) is to find some new *aspect* of the question that's sufficiently different and add it in, or find something in the answer that can be pursued separately, that's different enough that it's clearer if it's addressed in a new Q&A page. ([Now what do we think? Is this purple dot really caused by Cassegrain optics and coherent backscattering?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20072/12102))

Comment: different but related: [How common is it for spacecraft to have "selfie" capability?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19886/12102)